# Duplication of terminal in macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, macos-ventura

In macOS ventura I cannot duplicate my terminal app.

I want to do this as I have a M1 processor and I want to have one that opens using Rosetta2 and one that opens natively.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: It was never obvious (to me, anyway) how to start multiple instances of the same executable in macOS. Have they really disabled the ability to do that, or do you just need help finding out how to do that? (Either way, apple.stackexchange.com is probably a better site to ask at.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, needing a Terminal in Intel/Rosetta-mode to work with Azure Functions.

A simple workaround is to install a Terminal alternative, e.g iTerm 2, and set either that or Terminal to run in Rosetta mode.

Comment: Thank you, yes this is what I have been doing also. Any idea why there is not the option to duplicate certain apps in ventura?

Comment: Utilities % sudo cp -R Terminal.app Terminal-Rosetta.app
cp: Terminal-Rosetta.app: Operation not permitted
cp: Terminal.app: unable to copy extended attributes to Terminal-Rosetta.app: Operation not permitted

I get an error like this from terminal..

Here is an article explaining a bit about the error message and it suggests using rsync instead: https://www.quora.com/What-isnt-copied-when-Mac-OS-Xs-CP-complains-extended-attributes-not-copied

Rsync however gives me similar error.

Answer (score 24):

An alternative is a workaround posted [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718666) (to save you some time, I'm transcribing it here):

In your `~/.zshrc` file, add these two lines at the end:

```
alias arm="env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login"

alias intel="env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login"
```

From now on, from any new terminal window, you can type in `intel` or `arm` whenever you want to switch between using Rosetta2 or not, respectively

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution the most helpful ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718666))

Reason for failing: Apple disabled in OS Ventura the option to duplicate Terminal.App and rename it.

```
% env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login
% arch
arm64 


% env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login
% arch
x86_64
```

Add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```
alias arm="env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login"

alias intel="env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login"
```

Now, when in Terminal app, you can switch arch by using the aliases.